# CS0311 C# The type cannot be used as type parameter 'TContext' in the generic type or method. EntityFrameworkCore

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-fluent-api

I specify the context class I created in the entity project on the Startup.cs file and the connectionString data I created for connectionString. But why am I getting this error?

> ERROR message:
> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error CS0311  The type
> 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Implementation.UserContext'
> cannot be used as type parameter 'TContext' in the generic type or
> method
> 'EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.AddDbContext(IServiceCollection,
> Action, ServiceLifetime, ServiceLifetime)'.
> There is no implicit reference conversion from
> 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Implementation.UserContext'
> to
> 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext'.    EntityFramework2    C:\Users\xsamu\source\repos\EntityFramework2\EntityFramework2\Startup.cs    29  Active

Startup class:

```csharp
namespace EntityFramework2
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddDbContext<UserContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DevConnection")));
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Entity configuration:

```csharp
namespace EntityFramework2
{
    public class EntityConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<User>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<User> builder)
        {
            builder.HasOne<Department>(navigationExpression: s => s.Name)
                .WithOne(sa => sa.User)
                .HasForeignKey<Department>(sa => sa.DepartmentId);

            builder.HasOne<Title>(navigationExpression: s => s.TitleCode)
               .WithOne(sa => sa.User)
               .HasForeignKey<Title>(sa => sa.TitleId);

            builder.HasOne<Position>(navigationExpression: s => s.PositionCode)
               .WithOne(sa => sa.User)
               .HasForeignKey<Position>(sa => sa.PositionId);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How does `UserContext` look like?

Comment: What is the full error message?

Comment: Screenshot ------>  https://hizliresim.com/c44nn8

Answer (score 9):

> There is no implicit reference conversion from 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Implementation.UserContext' to 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext'.

The message tells you, that your `UserContext` class does not inherit from `DbContext`, which is mandatory.

It should look something like this:

```cs
public class BloggingContext : DbContext
{
    public BloggingContext(DbContextOptions<BloggingContext> options)
        : base(options)
    { }

    public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
}
```

For further information, see the [EF Core Tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/) and [Configuring a DbContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/configuring-dbcontext).

Comment: What about if I am inheriting from IdentityDbContext ?

Comment: @SubliminalHash That is fine, since it in turn inherits from `DbContext`. From [IdentityDbContext Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.entityframeworkcore.identitydbcontext?view=aspnetcore-7.0): Inheritance
`DbContext` → `IdentityUserContext<TUser,TKey,TUserClaim,TUserLogin,TUserToken>` → `IdentityDbContext<TUser,TRole,TKey,IdentityUserClaim<TKey>,IdentityUserRole<TKey>,IdentityUserLogin<TKey>,IdentityRoleClaim<TKey>,IdentityUserToken<TKey>>` → `IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser,IdentityRole,String>` → `IdentityDbContext`

Comment: it didn't like me using IdentityContext. Instead I left it at DbContext it worked fine. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 3):

Entity Framework requires You to inherit Your `UserContext` from the `DbContext` EFCore's base class.
Please double-check if you really did this (judging by the error message, you forgot about it).

Comment: Guess, You're right. Reprhased my answer to actually resemple an Answer.

Answer (score 1):

You get this message when you have a call and its interface but you forgot to let the class implement the interface.

`class UserContext : MyInterface`

Answer (score 1):

check your nuget package you install Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore  instead of Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;

AspNet instead of AspNetCore

that should do it

Comment: There is no "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore".

Comment: The correct name is Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore. But this answer helped me to find this package, I was using the old one on dotnet 6. So thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just make Your Context `UserContext` inherited from `DbContext` Class like the following Code and you are good to go:

```
public class UserContext : DbContext
{
    public UserContext (DbContextOptions<UserContext > options)
        : base(options)
    { }

    public DbSet<User> Users{ get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem happens because of the DbContext inheritance, I had the same problem while I was inheriting from IdentityDbcontext because it was inheriting and old package.

**I solved adding this package:** `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore`

FYI: IdentityDbcontext also inherits from DbContext.

Answer (score -2):

I faced similar issues in configuartion class. Earlier, the code was placed as `DbMigrationsConfiguration<UserContext>`. However reviewing the error below, the code has been updated and the error gone.

> Error CS0311  The type 'EntityFramework2.Data.UserContext' cannot be used as type parameter 'TContext' in the generic type or method 'DbMigrationsConfiguration'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'EntityFramework2.Data.UserContext' to 'System.Data.Entity.DbContext'.

Updated Code:

```cs
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<DbContext>
```

Comment: In what way does this answer the question?